# Do the following equations are linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I arrived in solving problems in linear algebra equations below.But I need to prove that the decision to conclude one of the four following equation is the result of the other three.

Can you help me to prove.....

$$a+b-\lambda(c-a)=0, \\ a\alpha-b-\lambda(d-b)=0, \\ c+d-\lambda c=0, \\ c\alpha-d-\lambda d=0$$

wich $\alpha \gt-1 $ is a constant.

Comment: Is $\lambda$ a constant as well?

Comment: You can evaluate the determinant.  [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant+%7B%7B1%2BL,1,-L,0%7D,%7BA,-1%2BL,0,-L%7D,%7B0,0,1-L,1%7D,%7B0,0,A,-1-L%7D%7D) gets me $(\alpha-\lambda^2+1)^2$.  Which means that this system is linearly dependent iff $\lambda^2 = \alpha+1$.

Comment: which one of  the equations turns out to be redundant?

Comment: yes λ is a positive constant...